# Trying to use bertopic within jupyter notebook but experiencing error when just importing into file

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, bert-language-model, huggingface

Been trying to test out some bertopic within a jupyter notebook file but experiencing an error. I just try to run this:

```
from bertopic import BERTopic
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
```

the output gives me an "AttributeError: module 'llvmlite.binding.ffi' has no attribute 'register_lock_callback'" error. I'm very confused as all I've done is do a

`pip install bertopic`

and that worked well, then I made this notebook a

i looked in my installed packages
`pip list`
and saw that bertopic was properly installed. I also tried updating jupyter notebook but didn't work

Any help would be appreciated